# Deserializing array of items with attribute

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-deserialization

I need to deserialize this block of data

```
<colors>
    <color id='mnemonic1'>RRGGBB1</color>
    <color id='mnemonic2'>RRGGBB2</color>
    <color id='mnemonic3'>RRGGBB3</color>
    <color id='mnemonic4'>RRGGBB4</color>
</colors>
```

if I define this

```
<XmlArray("colors")> <XmlArrayItem("color")> Public colors() As DefColor
..
Public Class DefColor
    <XmlAttribute("id")> Public id As String
    <XmlElement("color")> Public defColor As String
End Class
```

I'm able to read 'id' attribute but not 'color' string.
If I define as:

```
<XmlArray("colors")><XmlArrayItem("color")> Public colors() As String
```

I'm able to read only the 'color' value.   How can I read both ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

```
<XmlElement("color")> Public defColor As String
```

to

```
<XmlText>Public defColor As String
```

Anything Inside >(here)< is >(Text)<